# Postsharp and NUnit: how to intercept a TestFixtureSetup defined in a base class

Tags: c#, nunit, postsharp

I have a MethodInterceptionAspect that I use on unit tests (why I do that is a long story).

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method,
        AllowMultiple = false,
        TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance | MulticastAttributes.Public)]
[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Commute, typeof(TestWrapperAttribute))]
[Serializable]
public class TestWrapperAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
   public override bool CompileTimeValidate( MethodBase method )
   {
      return true;
   }
   public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
   {
   ... // some code here
   }
 }
```

I have a base test class and a derived test class

```
public class BaseTestClass
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void BaseTestFixtureSetUp()
    {  // ... code here
    }
}

[TestFixture]
[TestWrapper]
public class DerivedTestClass : BaseTestClass
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
    }
    // ... some more stuff here, Tests etc.
}
```

Now the problem is that my aspect's OnInvoke is executed on the DerivedClass TestFixtureSetup, but not on the base class' TestFixtureSetup.

Please note that I read the only post I could find in this direction (I will enter the link later) but that was about intercepting ToString() and the solution was defining a ToString() in the aspect and inserting it as override in the class. This situation is different, as I don't know the name of the method having the TestFixtureSetup attribute.

Comment: The easiest solution seems to be to apply the [TestWrapper] attribute in the base class directly. Is there a reason why you cannot do that? (i.e it's a class from a 3-rd party library)

Comment: Well, my example here is oversimplified. But The different derived classes want to add different behaviours through the attributes. Think: one base class, several derived classes, several attributes.

Comment: The aspect code is weaved into the target method at compile-time. If you want the base method to have different aspects applied for different derived classes, then this is not possible - there's only one version of the base method. If you want your base method to have all the aspects collected from all the derived classes in the same assembly, then it's realistic to achieve with aspect provider.

Comment: It may also be helpful to describe your specific use case and try to find the best fitting design for it. Now it looks like you need to solve a technical challenge of using PostSharp in a way it wasn't designed for.